OpenSSL version problem in ROS2 Humble install for Windows
I'm trying to install ROS2 Humble for Windows because I would like to create an environments for Oculus Quest and Unity and Isaac sim and ROS2.
I followed this official page but I noticed that OpenSSL 1.1.1 is not supported now and there is no OpenSSL 1.1.1 installers for Windows in this page
Where can I get the OpenSSL 1.1.1 installer for Windows??
Does anyone encounter the same problem and know alternative way?
I tried to install OpenSSL 3.0.12 and run the examples but I got this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\lib\demo_nodes_py\listener-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('demo-nodes-py==0.20.3', 'console_scripts', 'listener')())
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\demo_nodes_py\topics\listener.py", line 35, in main
    rclpy.init(args=args)
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\__init__.py", line 89, in init
    return context.init(args, domain_id=domain_id)
  File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\context.py", line 72, in init
    self.__context = _rclpy.Context(
rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.RCLError: Failed to initialize init options: failed to load any RMW implementations, at C:\ci\ws\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:125, at C:\ci\ws\src\ros2\rcl\rcl\src\rcl\init_options.c:75
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1


From ICS Download, at the bottom of the page:

OpenSSL Binaries Win-64 1.1.1w requires ICS V8.57 or later
OpenSSL Binaries Win-32 1.1.1w requires ICS V8.57 or later

Or just get the source code, from Index of /source/old/1.1.1, and compile it yourself  (see Compilation and Installation).
Alternative way: Set up a Linux box (or virtual machine) and do it in Linux.
